# Launching from Eclipses causes errors in browser

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I've got a strange situation; when I run a Flex app from Eclipse (i.e. click run as web app), my remote calls always hang.

In Firefox, they return as failed.

But when I open up a browser and browse to my .html file in the bin-debug folder, the remote calls work.

Why is that?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

p.s. I'm accessing a websphere server and authentication is required but a Java developer hardcoded his ID in.

Comment: Do you have debug version of flash installed? http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: Have you tried this:  1. Goto firefox config by typing about:config in the firefox address bar
2. Click on the I’ll be careful, I promise button.
3. Type dom.ipc.plugins.timeoutSecs
4. Find value and double click and change the value to -1

Comment: Yep, I have the debug version installed and I set the config in Firefox but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved today and the issue was getting through to the IBM websphere server; the authentication was still in place and the java developers had to create a cloned environment where authentication was not required. Thank you everyone for their helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check:

Do you have a breakpoint set in your code somewhere?  Eclipse may be waiting for you to interact with it so the program execution can continue.  On my Win7 machine, when the debugger takes over, eclipse often does not take over focus; so I have to manually minimize IE.

Comment: No breakpoints set and that is confirmed by the fact that when running Firefox, the remote calls fail. I also have a 2-monitor setup and run Eclipse in one and the browser in the other. On another note, it appears that navigation to the HTML file in the bin-debug folder circumvents the call to authenticate. Very strange behavior.